# Java JMS connection to HornetQ

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

We're using hornetQ, and got a separate java application which connects to the queue to read from it.
We're having a Connection to it, creating a JMS session from the connection,
then obtaining a JMS MessageConsumer from the session, then assigning a custom MessageListener to the MessageConsumer.
We call message.acknowledge() for every processed message.

This all works very well, but in the case where we kill our java-application in the middle of processing, before hitting acknowledge(), the message is removed from hornetQ, yet never processed, and lost forever.
It seems that our current java application JMS setup somehow works by removing from the queue, and then rolling back/re-inserting it, if something goes wrong.
But if we kill our application, there won't be any roll-back or re-inserting, as it happens within our client/java-code.

Is there a setting or delivery-mode or something I can configure in the client, that causes the HornetQ to treat every message as "not consumed"(and still in the queue) untill the client sends the ack, so that a rollback arent neccecary?

EDIT: Also tried using transactional mode, calling:

> connection.createSession(true, acknowledgementType)

Our MessageListener:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onMessage(Message message) {
>     LOGGER.debug("Message received. Going to handle message.");
>     try {
>         final TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) message;
>         final String text = messageReceived.getText();
>         LOGGER.debug(String.format("Message content:\n%s", text));
>         final boolean isMessageSent = eventDispatcher.handleEvent(text);
>         if (isMessageSent) {
>             LOGGER.error("Behold!");
>             message.acknowledge();
>             session.commit();
>         } else {
>           session.rollback();
>         }
>     } catch (JMSException jmse) {
>         LOGGER.error("Failed to get text from a message from the events queue.", jmse);
>     } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
>         LOGGER.error("Failed to deserialize contents of the message from the events queue.", jaxbe);
>     } catch (Exception ex) {
>         LOGGER.error("An error occurred when receiving an event from the events queue:", ex);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Use transactional mode. After sending/consuming the message, use session.commit().

Comment: I tried using a quick and dirty approach to check(added code for transaction in my question), but we're having the same issue. If the connection to the hornetQ goes down(we're testing it by shutting down hornetQ), while the onMessage() is chewing at eventDispatcher.handleEvent(), then the message is **LOST** from the hornetq. No rollback was commited, no commit/acknowledge was commited, and the message is gone from hornetq

Comment: Create session with: "Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);" And do not use both message.ackownledge() and session.commit() together (when using transacted session, message.ackownledge() has no impact).

Comment: We already tested with transacted=true as the first argument, according to the JMS documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#createSession-boolean-int-

It states that the second argument is ignored, if the first is set to true
(it also suggests using another create method, which do exactly the same but take only one option, but that shouldn't matter either)